# Handling archive contents as VFS?

Tags: java, file, filesystems, archive

I'm implementing someting like a file browser.Now I'm trying to recognize files inside archive virtually -the user could browse these files and return to other files in the filesystem-. So what is the best practice for this as I thought I do the following:

```
 public class VFile extends java.io.File{
     File archiveParent;
     ....
  }
```

Is there something better or any Library that could solve this in an easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/), which also [supports "mounting" archive files](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#Zip,%20Jar%20and%20Tar) (zip, jar, tar, gzip, bzip2).

Comment: I'm trying to access rar archive

Comment: That's not on their list :-(. You could follow their plugin architecture for your implementation, at least the interface seems mature.